# How can I tokenize a file content?

Tags: c, token, tokenize

I'm trying to read contains from a file `privateKey.txt` that contains the following and tokenized each block.

```
RSA Private-Key: (1024 bit, 2 primes)
modulus:
    00:a3:38:61:b8:4a:29:60:2c:2f:6c:df:3b:e1:9b:
    b9:13:96:8f:dc:7f:b4:5a:7c:6d:61:6e:f4:df:63:
    36:1b:7c:97:b9:f5:03:8e:40:7e:ca:48:00:5f:b6:
    a3:51:66:39:7b:d2:b6:f0:5e:5e:93:de:e0:ec:c6:
    ae:bb:c5:3d:50:be:ca:e1:02:d0:0b:e2:36:75:43:
    e0:64:81:25:92:a6:26:e3:55:d8:cf:fe:f5:44:4f:
    c5:d5:1d:8a:6e:d2:3e:61:50:72:95:26:a2:7f:8a:
    66:a6:57:da:58:13:c7:9a:d4:b7:cb:5d:c7:c7:5e:
    d4:94:e5:b8:cc:e2:c4:2c:c3
publicExponent: 65537 (0x10001)
privateExponent:
    21:19:4b:e7:bd:52:4a:a8:6b:2d:9e:cf:5b:de:e2:
    57:30:8f:17:dd:e5:ca:fb:b4:8a:af:9f:84:b5:6f:
    c1:7f:30:9d:8b:2c:1f:6a:c0:cb:70:72:72:f6:6c:
    84:13:40:d0:f5:58:17:c2:6b:57:7d:39:0b:8a:f6:
    e0:29:0d:57:c1:73:99:1a:e1:e7:bc:52:15:89:08:
    7e:d5:cb:dc:be:0b:af:32:4c:b1:f3:cc:ea:bc:95:
    1a:37:19:5c:de:94:be:ca:9b:57:fb:42:01:1c:42:
    db:d5:b2:d4:16:f7:f2:dd:7f:28:c4:bb:67:9d:21:
    ef:4b:d2:b8:78:cf:f6:61
prime1:
    00:d7:84:e9:f3:4a:2b:f9:c2:de:a4:ce:6c:5d:57:
    fa:bd:77:c3:83:55:cf:b0:42:c8:9d:e4:85:60:dd:
    c8:9a:e4:f8:52:80:ac:fa:cb:33:36:2f:cf:ad:8d:
    2a:7b:9e:6a:dc:6f:94:d9:91:0f:47:42:64:22:5d:
    d4:84:7d:85:99
prime2:
    00:c1:e0:b5:ca:28:7a:46:2f:d3:46:ec:86:7c:20:
    c2:49:d6:20:5c:aa:4a:c4:5f:fd:88:d0:ba:f2:e3:
    33:9a:d4:29:dc:94:5b:3c:05:99:2e:7f:a6:3a:73:
    34:e1:2a:58:a9:c4:69:c1:cf:ed:5c:b1:a8:45:e0:
    e0:cc:c2:06:bb
exponent1:
    0f:ed:f7:0c:d0:72:a7:a7:4b:a5:8a:cc:5f:a9:dd:
    12:9c:03:8b:75:90:40:4a:ef:61:1c:3e:ef:85:f5:
    09:dd:da:ac:de:6d:ea:ab:92:41:73:0f:3a:98:b0:
    87:2a:92:63:70:ab:e3:d8:e0:f4:37:68:07:52:40:
    1e:fa:d8:21
exponent2:
    63:f8:fd:84:aa:ee:b2:36:83:19:b5:69:7b:a4:60:
    cb:36:31:25:d7:62:0a:74:fd:05:89:ac:7d:06:8f:
    5b:ad:3f:90:d0:a7:63:01:f8:05:34:29:81:46:5a:
    e4:28:b3:e3:86:b6:8a:0c:2f:f7:76:5c:b0:fb:ce:
    af:86:f5:75
coefficient:
    00:c0:30:ec:87:5f:7b:d2:c6:ab:b8:17:3a:aa:de:
    7c:6b:3e:24:5d:12:ca:d6:87:7d:df:b8:28:df:b1:
    b6:c6:46:0b:13:98:82:2b:82:8b:ea:1a:2f:cd:5a:
    17:e5:54:a3:17:d6:e6:0f:68:c1:76:73:2e:08:8f:
    18:66:ef:b6:cd
```

I have the following code to read the file and tokenized each block,

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#define KEY_BUFFER_SIZE 2560
unsigned char private_size[2070];

int main() {

    FILE * fp2 = fopen ("privateKey.txt", "r");
    int size_key=KEY_BUFFER_SIZE;
    if(fp2){
        fread(private_size,1,sizeof (private_size),fp2);
        //fgets(private_size,sizeof (private_size),fp2);
    }
    fclose(fp2);

    while(size_key>0){
        size_key=size_key-1;
    }

    //printf("%s\n",private_size);


    char *token;
    int k=0, size;
    const char s[] = "\n ";
    unsigned char *rest=private_size;

    // get the first token
    token = strtok_r(rest, s, &rest);
    printf("First token %s\n",token);



    // walk through other tokens
    while( token != NULL ) {
        printf("token---> %s\n",token);
        token = strtok_r(rest, " \n", &rest);
        
    }

 return 0;
 }
```

**output:**

```
First token RSA
token---> RSA
token---> Private-Key: (1024 bit, 2 primes)
token---> modulus:
token--->     00:a3:38:61:b8:4a:29:60:2c:2f:6c:df:3b:e1:9b:
token--->     b9:13:96:8f:dc:7f:b4:5a:7c:6d:61:6e:f4:df:63:
token--->     36:1b:7c:97:b9:f5:03:8e:40:7e:ca:48:00:5f:b6:
token--->     a3:51:66:39:7b:d2:b6:f0:5e:5e:93:de:e0:ec:c6:
token--->     ae:bb:c5:3d:50:be:ca:e1:02:d0:0b:e2:36:75:43:
token--->     e0:64:81:25:92:a6:26:e3:55:d8:cf:fe:f5:44:4f:
token--->     c5:d5:1d:8a:6e:d2:3e:61:50:72:95:26:a2:7f:8a:
token--->     66:a6:57:da:58:13:c7:9a:d4:b7:cb:5d:c7:c7:5e:
token--->     d4:94:e5:b8:cc:e2:c4:2c:c3
token---> publicExponent: 65537 (0x10001)
token---> privateExponent:
token--->     21:19:4b:e7:bd:52:4a:a8:6b:2d:9e:cf:5b:de:e2:
token--->     57:30:8f:17:dd:e5:ca:fb:b4:8a:af:9f:84:b5:6f:
token--->     c1:7f:30:9d:8b:2c:1f:6a:c0:cb:70:72:72:f6:6c:
token--->     84:13:40:d0:f5:58:17:c2:6b:57:7d:39:0b:8a:f6:
token--->     e0:29:0d:57:c1:73:99:1a:e1:e7:bc:52:15:89:08:
token--->     7e:d5:cb:dc:be:0b:af:32:4c:b1:f3:cc:ea:bc:95:
token--->     1a:37:19:5c:de:94:be:ca:9b:57:fb:42:01:1c:42:
token--->     db:d5:b2:d4:16:f7:f2:dd:7f:28:c4:bb:67:9d:21:
token--->     ef:4b:d2:b8:78:cf:f6:61
token---> prime1:
token--->     00:d7:84:e9:f3:4a:2b:f9:c2:de:a4:ce:6c:5d:57:
token--->     fa:bd:77:c3:83:55:cf:b0:42:c8:9d:e4:85:60:dd:
token--->     c8:9a:e4:f8:52:80:ac:fa:cb:33:36:2f:cf:ad:8d:
token--->     2a:7b:9e:6a:dc:6f:94:d9:91:0f:47:42:64:22:5d:
token--->     d4:84:7d:85:99
token---> prime2:
token--->     00:c1:e0:b5:ca:28:7a:46:2f:d3:46:ec:86:7c:20:
token--->     c2:49:d6:20:5c:aa:4a:c4:5f:fd:88:d0:ba:f2:e3:
token--->     33:9a:d4:29:dc:94:5b:3c:05:99:2e:7f:a6:3a:73:
token--->     34:e1:2a:58:a9:c4:69:c1:cf:ed:5c:b1:a8:45:e0:
token--->     e0:cc:c2:06:bb
token---> exponent1:
token--->     0f:ed:f7:0c:d0:72:a7:a7:4b:a5:8a:cc:5f:a9:dd:
token--->     12:9c:03:8b:75:90:40:4a:ef:61:1c:3e:ef:85:f5:
token--->     09:dd:da:ac:de:6d:ea:ab:92:41:73:0f:3a:98:b0:
token--->     87:2a:92:63:70:ab:e3:d8:e0:f4:37:68:07:52:40:
token--->     1e:fa:d8:21
token---> exponent2:
token--->     63:f8:fd:84:aa:ee:b2:36:83:19:b5:69:7b:a4:60:
token--->     cb:36:31:25:d7:62:0a:74:fd:05:89:ac:7d:06:8f:
token--->     5b:ad:3f:90:d0:a7:63:01:f8:05:34:29:81:46:5a:
token--->     e4:28:b3:e3:86:b6:8a:0c:2f:f7:76:5c:b0:fb:ce:
token--->     af:86:f5:75
token---> coefficient:
token--->     00:c0:30:ec:87:5f:7b:d2:c6:ab:b8:17:3a:aa:de:
token--->     7c:6b:3e:24:5d:12:ca:d6:87:7d:df:b8:28:df:b1:
token--->     b6:c6:46:0b:13:98:82:2b:82:8b:ea:1a:2f:cd:5a:
token--->     17:e5:54:a3:17:d6:e6:0f:68:c1:76:73:2e:0
```

And I tried to tokenized depends on the `\n`. Idea was to get an entire block as a token. However, seems like it may not be the correct approach since I'm getting each line as a token.

How can I get an entire block like the following as a token?

```
00:a3:38:61:b8:4a:29:60:2c:2f:6c:df:3b:e1:9b:
b9:13:96:8f:dc:7f:b4:5a:7c:6d:61:6e:f4:df:63:
36:1b:7c:97:b9:f5:03:8e:40:7e:ca:48:00:5f:b6:
a3:51:66:39:7b:d2:b6:f0:5e:5e:93:de:e0:ec:c6:
ae:bb:c5:3d:50:be:ca:e1:02:d0:0b:e2:36:75:43:
e0:64:81:25:92:a6:26:e3:55:d8:cf:fe:f5:44:4f:
c5:d5:1d:8a:6e:d2:3e:61:50:72:95:26:a2:7f:8a:
66:a6:57:da:58:13:c7:9a:d4:b7:cb:5d:c7:c7:5e:
d4:94:e5:b8:cc:e2:c4:2c:c3
```

Comment: it looks like the tabs or spaces at beginning of a line are significant, so tokenization probably not the best approach.

Comment: @GarrGodfrey, any alternative that you can think of?

Comment: read by lines and append the line to previous if it starts with \t or spaces? (I can't tell what is really in the file)

Comment: I don't think you are using strtok_r correctly, though. Subsequent calls should pass NULL for the first parameter, and you should use the same delimiter string each time. It should be delimiting on spaces but your output doesn't show that.

Comment: `like the following as a token?` You never tried to do it, you only printed the contents of the file. Find in the string `modulus:`, then find `publicExponent` - anything in between is the stuff you are looking for.